Screen starts off with light or dark mode, and changes to dark or light mode depending on user settings
I am making a light mode and dark mode for my app using data store.
As I open the application, and depending on whether the device is on dark mode, the application starts off with dark mode, and then suddenly switches to light mode (if the user has set the app to light mode).
This also happens if the the device is not on dark mode, then the application starts off with light mode, and then suddenly switches to dark mode (if the user has set the app to dark mode).
HomeMenuActivity class
class HomeMenuActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    //UI elements
    private lateinit var settingsButton: ConstraintLayout

    //primitive values
    private var booleanNightMode: Boolean = false

    //instantiations
    private lateinit var appSettingsDarkModeViewModel: AppSettingsDarkModeViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        installSplashScreen()
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_menu)
        setupUI()
    }

    private fun setupUI(){

        settingsButton = findViewById(R.id.button_settings)

        loadDataStoreValues()

    }

    private fun loadDataStoreValues(){

        appSettingsDarkModeViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[AppSettingsDarkModeViewModel::class.java]

        Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({

            appSettingsDarkModeViewModel.getTheme.observe(this){ pref ->
                booleanNightMode = pref
            }
            settings()
        },0)

    }

    private fun settings(){

        Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
            if(booleanNightMode){
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)
            }
            else{
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
            }
            setupButtons()
        },50)
    }

    private fun setupButtons(){

        settingsButton.setOnClickListener{
            val nextPage = Intent(this, SettingsMenuActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(nextPage)
            finish()
        }
    }
}

AppSettingsDarkModeDataStore class
private val Context.dataStore by preferencesDataStore("THEME_KEY")

class AppSettingsDarkModeDataStore(context: Context) {

    private val dataStore = context.dataStore

    companion object {
        val darkModeKey = booleanPreferencesKey("DARK_MODE_KEY")
    }

    suspend fun setTheme(isDarkMode : Boolean){
        dataStore.edit { pref ->
            pref[darkModeKey] = isDarkMode
        }
    }

    val getTheme : Flow<Boolean> = dataStore.data
            .catch { exception ->
                if(exception is IOException) {
                    emit(emptyPreferences())
                }
                else {
                    throw exception
                }
            }
            .map { pref ->
                val uiMode = pref[darkModeKey] ?: false
                uiMode
            }
    }

AppSettingsDarkModeViewModel class
class AppSettingsDarkModeViewModel(application: Application): AndroidViewModel(application) {

    private val repository = AppSettingsDarkModeDataStore(application)

    val getTheme = repository.getTheme.asLiveData()

    fun setTheme(isDarkMode : Boolean) = viewModelScope.launch {
        repository.setTheme(isDarkMode)
    }
}

I have also attempted runBlocking in the view model class (as well as the home menu activity, but all it did was cause the screen to flicker to white or black whenever I went to the next or previous screen. I even attempted to put the 'Dispatchers.IO' inside the asLiveData bracket, but that made no difference.

I'm not using datastore nor XML but in my compose app i experienced an issue like this and I solved it by using shared preference and the selected theme was Int based(0 -light, 1- dark, 3- system).
Make a mutablestateflow to store theme value
On app start retrieve the theme from shared preference and update the state flow
When you change the theme of the app, you update the state flow snd also update the shared preference with the new theme value
